# toString() method vs string representation

Tags: javascript

I have:

```js
let N = new Number(42);
console.log(N);   // [Number: 42]
console.log(N.toString());  // 42
```

In the second line, what does the notation using square brackets mean?

The `console.log()` documentation says the "string representation" of the object argument is printed. If that is not the same as the `toString()` function of the `Number` object, where is the string representation of an object defined?

---

Afternote: I was using Node REPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `[Number: 42]` in your example is just the format used by the console you're using to show you a `Number` object that has the underlying primitive value `42`. That format varies by console. For instance, the console built into Chrome (and other Chromium-based browsers) shows `Number {42}`:

[image: Chrome console showing Number {42}]

If you expand it, you see more information:

[image: Chrome console showing a Number object showing its prototype is also a Number object and its [[PrimitiveValue]] internal slot is 42]

It's important to realize that `new Number(42)` is a **very** unusual thing to do. It creates a `Number` object. Normally you don't want a `Number` object, you just want a number primitive (`let N = 42` or more idiomatically `let n = 42`).

There are object equivalents to primitives for various reasons (`String` for strings, `Boolean` for booleans, etc.), but it's rare to actually want to use them explicitly. They're mostly there as a mechanism for specifying methods that can be accessed on the primitives, such as `toFixed` on numbers, which comes from `Number.prototype.toFixed`. When you use a method on a primitive, under the covers the method from the prototype object that that number *would* have if it were converted to its equivalent number is used. So for a primitive number, the method on `Number.prototype` (the object that the equivalent number object would have) is used.

---

In a comment you've said:

> From what I understand, `let n=42; console.log(n);` implicitly converts `n` to a `Number` object and then invoking its `toString` method.

Not usually, no. Usually a console has built-in handling and doesn't use `toString`, though of course this varies by console. But for example, Chrome's console doesn't:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "toString", {
    value() {
        return "!!!";
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
let n = 42;
                            // What Chrome shows:
console.log(n);             // 42 (shown as a number)
console.log(new Number(n)); // Number {42}
console.log(String(n));     // 42 (shown as a string)
console.log(n.toString());  // !!!
```

```html
Look at the browser's actual console.
```

What you see when you run that will depend on your browser, but at the moment Chrome shows:

[image: Chrome console showing 42 as a number, Number {42}, 42 as a string, and then !!!]

Comment: I see, so the output is a characteristic of the `console.log` function. From what I understand, `let n=42; console.log(n);` implicitly converts `n` to a `Number` object and then invoking its `toString` method. I was investigating out of curiosity.

Comment: @OldGeezer - *"From what I understand, `let n=42; console.log(n);` implicitly converts `n` to a `Number` object and then invoking its `toString` method. "* Not usually, no. :-) I've added to the answer to cover that.